# How to use the same skeleton in all characters inside the game

Tags: unreal-engine4

I have inside my game 20+ character that are all the same thing with diffrent mesh, same animations, same blueprints etc…

But in every update i will add 8 more characters, and i’m forced to do every change i’m doing in 20+ characters and that takes time.

I know that i can retarget some animations with a base skeleton and then just creating the animations for all characters, but this does not solve the problem with the character logic & code and does not redusing the final game size.

**I was wonder how epic games manage to do that in fortnite with so many skins…**

I’m sure that there is a solution to this problem that i can’t find.

Answer (score 1):

Epic games has mastered the art of reskinning.

The secret is dynamic loading/binding to a common framework.

Each Fortnight skin is unique in appearence and common in skeletal structure, allowing it to fill a generic slot in the engine.

Your builds have no generics applied to them, so every animation must be baked separately.